# Apache Cordova - Detect Android Home button press

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have a project which uses angularjs and I use Cordova to build project to android app. In my project, I add `ngCordova` and I want to use event when client click home button in device.

I readed http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/ but I did not find anything I need. Does anybody can help me or have any idea I can use?

Comment: As far as I know there is not explicit event for this, but you can use the pause event. It's called everytime the app is going to the background (which is the case when pressing the home button). Take a look at the [documentation here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause).

Comment: I know but when I have a message, the pause event is active and I don't want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no event in cordova for Home button press. You can detect application resume and pause events:

```
 // device APIs are available
//  be sure to add the listener in the device ready event
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

//runs when the app is on background
function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
}

//runs when the app resumes
function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
}
```

More info can be found on the [official cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

Comment: Oh. But if I use function onPause or onResume when I have a message this function will active. I don't want to function onPause or onResume active when I have message

Comment: @NguyễnPhúc you must handle when pause and resume will run using your own logic. for example `if (message) {//do nothing} else {//do things}`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I resovled this error. Thank Akis. I did as you said :)

Comment: @NguyễnPhúc if my answer gave you the solution to your problem then can you please mark it as answered?

Comment: please reply to this ques I am stuck here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282721/ionic-resume-pause-event-prevent-from-fire-on-file-browse-only-fire-at-press-the