# ionic resume pause event prevent from fire on file browse only fire at press the home button

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing a chat app inside I am using on pause and on resume event.

document.addEventListener('pause',onpause, false);

document.addEventListener('resume' , onresume,false);

This event works perfectly when I open the app and press home button to an Android phone these events are perfect.
But my problem is that in chat app I am sending file attachments from the gallery when I select the browse button the phone image gallery, and same time pause event is fire.  while I am on image gallery at a not selecting any image same time when I click on the home button the same event is not firing. So how I can prevent the pause event while selecting the file from the gallery.

Is there any other way to do this in **ionic v1**? Or how I can fire on pause and on resume event for the same.

Comment: any reply for this??

Comment: resume and pause events  doesn't "care" how the application was put in the background. It might be anything, like selecting an image from image gallery as you said. For this reason you have to manually handle when the resume and pause events code will run. I think the answer that @Volker gives is towards this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small Service to solve that problem:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
    protected resumeHalted = false;
    protected resumeSubject = new Subject<any>();

    protected resumeListener = () => {
        if (this.resumeHalted) {
            return;
        }
        this.resumeSubject.next();
    };

    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener('resume', this.resumeListener);
    }

    haltResume() {
        this.resumeHalted = true;
    }

    continueResume() {
        this.resumeHalted = false;
    }

    resume() {
        return this.resumeSubject;
    }
}
```

The gallery call is also wrapped in a service. Every time I call it, I "halt" the event and "continue" it after the user interaction finishes:

```js
getPicture(options: CameraOptions) {
    let subject = new Subject<any>();
    
    this.eventService.haltResume();
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((path) => {
        // ...
        subject.next();
        subject.complete();
        this.eventService.continueResume();
    }, () => {
        this.eventService.continueResume();
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

The last step: Instead of listening for the resume event, I subscribe to the resume Oberservable:

```js
        this.eventService.resume().subscribe(() => {
            this.statusBar.hide();
        });
```

Comment: @Pritish sorry, don't have any Ionic 1 projects anymore. In theory you just have to translate it into one of AngularJS Providers https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the pause event before you open the gallery and reattach the event on the gallery's callback.

```
document.removeEventListener("pause", myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using Ionic 1 or 2, but for both versions you have the lifecycle events.

Here are the ones for Ionic 2 (scroll down to "Lifecycle events")
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Here are the ones for Ionic 1
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/order-of-lifecycle-events/28251/2

Comment: I am using Ionic 1

Comment: This is about the lifecycle events of Ionic 1 - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/order-of-lifecycle-events/28251/2